# Does a workaround for value just being moved exist?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I wanted to create a structure containing my read and write buffer, I have tried different approach but i always get Value used after being moved or second mutable borrow occurs here. Is it possible to achieve what i want to do ?

```
struct MonitorInteraction {
   writer: BufWriter<TcpStream>,
   reader: BufReader<TcpStream>
}

impl MonitorInteraction {
   fn new(tcp_stream: TcpStream) -> MonitorInteraction {
      return MonitorInteraction {
         writer: BufWriter::new(tcp_stream),
         reader: BufReader::new(tcp_stream),
      }
   }
}
```